# Can't see Developer options > Root access

Tags: android, database, root, ddms

As I am testing my app on my phone I need to delete the database in `data/data`. But when I click on `data/` in my Eclipse DDMS on my phone, nothing happends.

I can't see "Root access" when I go to "Developer options" on my phone.

Could anyone tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android usage, belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

you dont have root access on device but in emulator you do have. thats why you can not view app information or data that is stored on android device.in order to view that data you have to root your device.